# Can "driver.findElement" be used as method and be called in a program

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am using "driver.findElement" multiple times. So can it be saved in a method and called multiple times?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody[@id='detailsstockid']/tr/td[12]/a/input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("supplier_name")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='supplier_name']/option[7]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("catagory_name")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("productname")).sendKeys("AutoProductNew");
driver.findElement(By.id("productcode")).sendKeys("ap02");
```

Comment: Why? Can you show us an example of how you would use this and why? What's the gain?

Answer (score 2):

You just need a wrapper like this

```
public static WebElement findElement(By locator){

WebElement anElement = driver.findElement(locator);


return anElement;
}

findElement(By.id("id")).click();
```

Basically you can call whatever method available to the object

Comment: ...but why would you do this? You wrote 3 lines of code and you still have to write one line of code to call it... there's no savings whatsoever. If you just leave the driver.findElement() call, anyone with Selenium knowledge will know what that does. If you change it to the code above, someone has to go into that function to figure out what it does. Please don't use code like this. It adds nothing and just adds another level of complexity where it's not needed.

Comment: @JeffC. There is no benefit to store driver.findElement in method. Better we can use as it is. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: With method like that you can synchronise browser and webElements (e.g.through the use of explicit wait), that way the browser waits for elements for a specific period of time. using driver.findElement isn't ideal in any test as the tests might be flakey. hope this helps plus the readability of the method clearly states its purpose.

Comment: You shouldn't be waiting for every call to .findElement. There's no need. You should wait for the page to load and then proceed... at that point you don't need to wait for individual elements. The only exception is of AJAX calls or changes to the page but in those cases you should only wait for those elements in specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to simplify your code... maybe make it more human readable. This is a noble goal but I would suggest that you take a different approach. Without more info, I don't know what your typical script is like. From the example code you provided, I would assume that you are going to a few pages, clicking on things, filling in textboxes, etc. I would suggest that you look into the page object model.

There are a LOT of references on the web on this topic, here's a good one to start with.
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern

The basic concept is create one Class file per page. [Page doesn't always literally mean an entire page. For example, I would create a separate page object for each popup dialog.] What this allows you to do is to consolidate all the code specific to that page into a single location. If you know what an API is and understand it, you will basically create an API for each page/dialog you touch. If done properly, it will greatly simplify and organize your code and will make creating new scripts drastically easier and they will be much easier to read. The benefits are numerous... one big one is code maintenance is made SO much easier. Imagine you have 100 scripts that all start by logging into the site. Let's assume the design of the login page changes... without the page object model, you will have to update all 100 scripts individually. If you are using the page object model, you open the LoginPage.java class, make the change to the Login() method, and you just fixed all 100 scripts.

You may be asking... how does this answer my question? What it does is turns

```
driver.findElement(By.id("supplier_name")).click();
```

into

```
somePage.clickSupplierName();
```

in your actual script. I think this is more along the lines of what you are asking without answering your specific question. The .findElement code still exists, but is "hidden away" in the page object.

A simple example. I wrote a script, with supporting page objects, to navigate to Amazon.com, search for Star Wars, return the # of found items, and then navigate to the Today's Deals page. The entire code is below.

program.java (Main script)

```
public class program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");

        // HOME PAGE
        HomePage homepage = new HomePage(driver);
        homepage.search("star wars");

        // SEARCH RESULTS PAGE
        SearchResultsPage searchResultsPage = new SearchResultsPage(driver);
        System.out.println(searchResultsPage.getNumberOfResults());

        // navigate to the Today's Deals page
        searchResultsPage.clickTodaysDealsLink();

        // TODAY'S DEALS PAGE
        // do more stuff

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

HomePage.java (Home page page object)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class HomePage
{
    WebDriver driver;
    private By searchTextboxLocator = By.id("twotabsearchtextbox");

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void search(String searchString)
    {
        driver.findElement(searchTextboxLocator).sendKeys(searchString + "\n");
    }
}
```

SearchResultsPage.java (Search results page page object)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class SearchResultsPage
{
    WebDriver driver;
    private By todaysDealsLinkLocator = By.linkText("Today's Deals");
    private By numberOfResultsLocator = By.id("s-result-count");

    public SearchResultsPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String getNumberOfResults()
    {
        // grabs only the total count of search results from the string in the form "1-16 of 7,488,146 results for "
        return driver.findElement(numberOfResultsLocator).getText().split(" ")[2];
    }

    public void clickTodaysDealsLink()
    {
        driver.findElement(todaysDealsLinkLocator).click();
    }
}
```